# Who else has been credited as "grandfather of the Russian revolution"?

Tags: russian-revolution

**Kropotkin** is known as "grandfather of the Russian revolution". Not sure who first gave him this title, but mass media of that time used it.

**Lenin** got the title post-mortem.

To my surprise, **Nikolai Tchaikovsky** also was given the same title. A real one which was given to him during his life.

It happened that asking this question in English, I've realized that the key term I am asking about is not quite popular across the world. But let me try anyway – which people were commonly credited as "grandfathers" of the Russian Revolution?

I am seeking for this exact term as it is used in literature.

Comment: I think the question might be clearer if it went "which people were commonly credited as 'grandfathers' of the Russian Revolution.' Also clarify if you are seeking for that exact term, or if other honorifics also count.

Comment: @o.m. - Fortunately, we have the technology to make such things happen...

Comment: @T.E.D., I hesitate to make significant changes to other people's posts. Easier to ask.

Comment: **Lenin got the title post-mortem.** I have never heard Lenin being called a 'grandfather of the revolution'. Only 'grandfather Lenin', which has nothing to do with the revolution, but with 'children literature', where this nickname occurs. When I hear the phase 'grandfather Lenin' it has never sounded to me like it was to to refer to Lenin's role in the revolution.

Comment: This is not a scientific term, hence, anybody can call anybody else a grandfather of something. For instance, if I were to write a post on reddit claiming that, say, Alexander II, Dmitry Mendeleev and Alexander Pushkin (my choice of names is nearly random)  were grandfathers of the Russian Revolution, would this count?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Exactly. Alexander III and Nicholas II contributed greatly (albeit unwittingly) to the Revolution.